# How to add access keys to menu items?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, menuitem

```
<MenuItem x:Name="newProjectButton" Click="OnNewProjectButton_Click" Header="_New Project">
</MenuItem>
```

I want to call OnNewProjectButton_Click whenever Alt+N is pressed. The code above doesn't work, unfortunately, because the handler is called only if the menu is expanded (i.e. has focus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ApplicationCommands.New](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.new.aspx) for this since it already provides that functionality.  The default [WPF Command Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx) is pretty cool.  Even if you decide not to use the default commanding model, that second link should show you how to hook up the input gestures you need.

EDIT:  Here is a sample implementation...

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.New" 
                    CanExecute="NewApplicationCommand_CanExecute"
                    Executed="NewApplicationCommand_Executed" />
</Window.CommandBindings>

<Grid>

    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem Command="ApplicationCommands.New" Header="_New Project"  />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>

</Grid>
```

And the code behind...

```
    private void NewApplicationCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Whatever logic you use to determine whether or not your
        // command is enabled.  I'm setting it to true for now so 
        // the command will always be enabled.
        e.CanExecute = true;
    }

    private void NewApplicationCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("New command executed");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You see to set the [InputGestureText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem.inputgesturetext.aspx) on the menu item

```
<MenuItem Header="Paste" 
 ToolTip="Paste the selected text to text box" 
 InputGestureText="Ctrl+V" />
```

But unlike WinForms the ["The application must handle the user's input to carry out the action"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747430.aspx#menus_with_shortcutkeys).

So consider using the WPF [commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx) as they do this for you automatically.  I found that [Windows Presentation Foundation Unleashed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672328917) covers this well.